# Can't fill a country with color in openstreetmap

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openstreetmap

[image]

I'm trying fill country with any color. I'm loading country borders like: http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/148838/full , but it doesn't work. Borders are colored, but figure is not being filled.

I'm using following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>

<body>
<div style="margin: 30px;">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://openlayers.org/en/v4.3.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <div id="map" class="map" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></div>
    <script>
        var map = new ol.Map({
            layers: [
                new ol.layer.Tile({
                    source: new ol.source.OSM()
                })
            ],
            target: 'map',
            view: new ol.View({
                center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([0, 0]),
                zoom: 1
            })
        });

        var areaLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            title: 'Boundaries',
            source: new ol.source.Vector({
                url: 'http://www.openstreetmap.org/api/0.6/relation/148838/full',
                format: new ol.format.OSMXML()
            }),
            style: new ol.style.Style({
                zIndex: 100,
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: 'rgba(246, 99, 79, 1.0)',
                    width: 3
                }),
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(246, 99, 79, 1.0)'
                })
            })
        });

        map.addLayer(areaLayer);
    </script>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

How to fill the country with color?

Answer (score 1):

The OSM API you are calling returns linestring geometries, which do not support a fill color.

If you're curious, you can view the geom as follows:

```
areaLayer.getSource().getFeatures()[0].getGeometry()
```

I would also recommend that you use the debug version when developing (ol-debug.js).

Comment: Thank you! So there is no way I can fill polygon using this xml feed data?

Comment: You will need to find a source of polygon country boundaries, which should not be difficult - a web search for "geojson country boundaries" yields a lot of options.